# Mnemonic for parallel

Tags: mnemonic

Is there a nice mnemonic for the spelling of the word

> parallel

I just can't remember how many "l" there are and where.

Comment: @Josh61, two "ll" at the end would be parallel, too. And two pairs of "l" would be even more paralleler. But thanks, at least that helps remember that there is at least one pair of "l". And thanks for the link!

Comment: The best way to remember, is the old way. Hand write the word fifty times on a piece of paper, guaranteed. You'll probably want to stop after the tenth but keep going! :)

Comment: I go by "Do not put the double l where I think it should be".

Comment: @painfulenglish... oddly enough that is actually very helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this question is opinion-based or not, so I'll provide an answer anyway.

Associate the word *parallel* with the number **121.** If you can do that because of that number's pattern, you don't need to remember how to find which number to use, but double *L* looks like eleven. 11 × 11 = 121.

Use the digits in order to help with common misspellings: one *R*, two *Ls* then one *L*: **parallel.**

Comment: You didn't explicitly mention it, but **parallel = corresponding = "one-to-one"** *(one **R**, to/two **L**s then one **L**)*. That works for me without needing to remember my 11 times table!

Answer (score 4):

Parallel mnemonic:

- **Par all el**ephants

You don't need to remember the *par* bit because it's in the original word. *All elephants* should do the trick for the end.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

> The para**ll**el train tracks go through the middle of my town.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the information on etymonline can help.
[Parallel](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=parallel&searchmode=none) Greek *para* meaning "beside" and Greek *allos* meaning "other".

As a mnemonic aid you could say the double l in the middle consists of two parallel lines.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine building a railway track (surely one of the easiest sets of parallel lines to picture).

**P**ick **A** **R**oute **A**nd **L**ay **L**ines **EL**egantly